# Looping through different dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have multiple controls on a page that are all similar and are all numbered.  For instance, I have multiple month controls like this:

- `Replacement1MonthDropDownList`
- `Replacement2MonthDropDownList`
- `Replacement3MonthDropDownList`
- Etc.

But when I have common code that works on all of the controls, I need a big `Select Case` statement like this:

```
Select Case Count
    Case 1
        Call Me.FillReplacements(rf.Replacements(0), Me.Replacement1MonthDropDownList, Me.Replacement1AmountTextBox, Me.ReplacementSaveButton)
    Case 2
        Call Me.FillReplacements(rf.Replacements(0), Me.Replacement1MonthDropDownList, Me.Replacement1AmountTextBox, Me.ReplacementSaveButton)
        Call Me.FillReplacements(rf.Replacements(1), Me.Replacement2MonthDropDownList, Me.Replacement2AmountTextBox, Me.SplitButton1)
```

Is it possible to loop through the controls and get them by name--justreplacing the numbers in the name with the current `Count` in my loop?

Sorry, I'm very new to Visual Basic! :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The `Page` class (`Me`, in this case) has a [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) method which allows you to find a control by name.  So, for instance, you could do something like this:

```
Dim monthControl As Control = Me.FindControl("Replacement" & Count.ToString() & "MonthDropDownList")
Dim splitControl As Control = Me.FindControl("SplitButton" & Count.ToString())
```

If you need to cast them as a more specific type, you could use `DirectCast`.  For instance:

```
Dim monthControl As DropDownList = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Replacement" & Count.ToString() & "MonthDropDownList"), DropDownList)
```

Alternatively, and perhaps preferably, you could make an array of controls so you could access them by index.  For instance, if you had an array like this defined:

```
Private monthControls() As DropDownList = {Replacement1MonthDropDownList, Replacement2MonthDropDownList, Replacement3MonthDropDownList}
```

Then you could access it by index like this:

```
Dim currentMonthControl As DropDownList = monthControls(Count)
```